# How to set Typescript --outDir to be root folder

Tags: typescript

I have the following project structure:

```
root
  -src
    -lib
      index.ts
    -example
      test.ts
```

I would like to set the outDir to be the root folder `/` so that I end up with this:

```
root
  -lib
    index.js
  -example
    test.js
  -src
    -lib
      index.ts
    -example
      test.ts
```

So that I can publish to npm with lib in the root folder and `.npmignore` the example folder along with the src folder ending up with just

```
root
  -lib
    index.js
```

I have tried setting `outDir` to `""`, `"/"` and `"./"` but they do not work. I do not know where the compiled files go but no example or lib folders appear in the root.

Is this possible?
Is there a better way or organising my code so that I can easily ignore certain folders?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Of course, as soon as I posted this and returned to the code it worked!

Setting outDir to `""` does do exactly what I want - I don't know why it didn't work before I asked this questions!